# OrientDB callback after record is persisted in server

Tags: orientdb, eventsource

I'm implementing record versioning using OrientDB, but its callback seems to be invoked right after OOBjectDatabaseTx#save(Object) is called.
Is there any way to get an additional callback for persisted record?

Comment: You can try to implement it using hooks, see: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Dynamic-Hooks.html / http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Java-Hooks.html

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko Thank you for your fast answer. But I have tried them without any success
Java-Hook is the worse because it does not listen to server events
Some other variants like Dynamic Hook and Live Query also do not work because with high contention some events are dropped
eg. with 1000 requests it receive only 998 and yet only 577 changes were made  ` record updated Test#337:0{firstname:Johnathan,reqId:997,lastname:Doe} v577`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that we can use ODatabaseListener for this purpose